# How to cut words that match from collection of sentences?

Tags: scala

I have a quick question about Scala part string matching. Consider the example:

```
val s1 = "game of thrones"
val s2 = Array("thrones videos", "watch game", "game of thrones stuff")
```

and I want to do some kind of regex or matching or `contains` such that in the result should be some thing like:

```
Array("videos", "watch", "stuff")
```

where any word in the string that is repeated in `s1` is cut out. What would be the most efficient way?

I am currently doing it by making `s1` into a regex and applying it to each line of `s2`, but I am also having trouble with getting it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure is the most 'efficient' way to do it (depends what you mean with efficient), but here we go:

```
 val ss1 = s1.split("\\s").toSet  //make a set of the words you have
 //ss1: Array[String] = Array(game, of, thrones)

 val ss2 = s2.map(_.split("\\s").toSet -- ss1).flatten  //make a set of words and remove the ones in ss1
 // Array[String] = Array(throne, videos, watch, stuff)
```

Comment: This might suit OP's needs, but it's worth mentioning that you might lose the order of the words in `s2`, since `Sets` don't have an ordering.  For example, `(Set(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) -- Set(1, 2)).toList` returns `List(5, 3, 4)` (and that could change with different versions of Scala or after updates!)

Answer (score 3):

This is achievable using `split`, `contains`, `map` and `filter`.  The key is to first build the list of words you're filtering, by using `split`:

```
val s1Words = s1.split(" ")
```

Now, for each string in `s2`, you want to similarly use `split`, filter out words that appear in `s1Words`, and then turn it back into a string:

```
s2.map(_.split(" ").filterNot(s1Words.contains).mkString(" "))
```

You might also turn `s1Words` into a set, and then use the `apply` method on `Set`, which tests for containment:

```
val s1Words = s1.split(" ").toSet
s2.map(_.split(" ").filterNot(s1Words).mkString(" "))
```

If the words in `s2` are separator by a set of characters other than space, you might prefer to use regex so that you can capture the separator, and then replace it in the call to `mkString`.